# Smallest possible value of $a$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do you find the smallest value of $a$ where:

$b^a \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

$b$ is not divisible by $p$, and $p$ is a prime number.

Fermat's little theorem works, but it doesn't ensure that $a$ is minimised.

What else could be used?

Comment: Unless you're given more information about $b$, you would have to check every factor of $p-1$.

Comment: You need to find multiplicative order $(d)$(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativeOrder.html) & one of the clues is that $d$ must divide $\phi(p)=p-1$

Comment: If you are lucky and you know the prime divisors of $p-1$, and there are not many, there is a fairly quick algorithm.

Comment: do you mean p is not divisible by b, because 1 to the power of anything will equal 1 mod anything

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: What is the technique you mentioned called?

Comment: @green I am not aware of it having any name in particular.  I suppose you could call it an application of [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)) if you have to call it something.  As Andre indicates, you can save some computation by using the prime factors of $p-1$